# It's about problem 8 in project euler , i can't tell why the code doesn't give me the correct answer

Tags: c

The 1000 digit :

```
 char dig_num[] = ("73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
            "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
            "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
            "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
            "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
            "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
            "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
            "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
            "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
            "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
            "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
            "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
            "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
            "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
            "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
            "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
            "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
            "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
            "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
            "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");
```

I've signed two values a res for the product and max for the largest one:

```
    unsigned long long int res;
unsigned long long int max;
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
int i;
int j;
i = 0;
max = 0;

while(i < (sizeof(dig_num) - 13))
{
    j = 1;
    res = dig_num[i] - 48;
     while(j < 13)
     {
         res *= dig_num[i + j] - 48;
         j++;
     }
     if(res > max && res != 0)
     {
        max = res;
     }

    i++;
}
 printf("%d",max);
```

It outputs the correct answer for 4 digit but why is it giving me a wrong answer when i put 13 ? Isn't unsigned long long enough for holding a large number ?

Comment: you need to debug your code

Comment: Did your compiler not give you any warning messages? Try adding `-Wall` to the command line arguments and see if it flags anything up. And as @bolov said, you should learn how to debug your code.

Comment: You can't print long long with`%d`

Comment: (a) State the problem in the question; do not just refer to it as Project Euler problem 8. (b) Include a [mre] in the question, include a **complete** program, the output you observe, and either the output you expect or an indication of how you know whether the output is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 compiler warnings/errors in your code:

The array initialization gives `error: array initialized from parenthesized string constant [-Werror=pedantic]`, so remove the `()` around the string.

The `printf` line gives `format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long unsigned int’ [-Werror=format=]`. The correct format specifier is `%llu` for `unsigned long long`.

After fixing these problems, it gives a number, which could be the correct one:
https://ideone.com/Z7LSuq

Please do not use the magic number `48`, use `'0'` instead.